# Regression in FOR loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, regression

I have the following code:

```
colBIN = {0.050, 0.055, 0.060, 0.065, 0.070, 0.075, 0.080, 0.085, 0.090, 0.095,0.1};

for i = 1 : length(colBIN)-1
    colBIN{i,2} = find(cols(:,1) <= cell2mat(colBIN(i+1,1)) & cols(:,1) > cell2mat(colBIN(i,1)));
end

rowBIN = {0.045, 0.046, 0.047, 0.048, 0.049, 0.050, 0.051, 0.052};

for i = 1 : length(rowBIN)-1
    rowBIN{i,2} = find(rows(:,1) <= cell2mat(rowBIN(i+1,1)) & rows(:,1) > cell2mat(rowBIN(i,1))); 
end

binCombos = cell(length(rowBIN)-1,length(colBIN)-1);

for m = 1 : length(rowBIN)-1
    for n = 1 : length(colBIN)-1
        binCombos{n,m} = intersect( rowBIN{m,2}(:,1),colBIN{n,2}(:,1));
    end
end


binRows = size(binCombos,1);
binCols = size(binCombos,2)-1;

j = j + 1;
for n = 1 : binRows; 
    for m = 1 : binCols;
       thisBin = binCombos{n,m}(:,:); 
       if isempty(thisBin)==0

       %polyfit
       quadmod = polyfit(x_vrbl(thisBin), y_vrbl(thisBin), 2);
       interval = 0.0:0.001:1;
       quadmodcurve = polyval(quadmod,interval); 
       [r2 rmse] = rsquare(y_vrbl(thisBin), quadmodcurve); 
       plot(x_vrbl(thisBin), y_vrbl(thisBin), '*', interval, quadmodcurve);
       xlabel('x_vrbl');
       ylabel('y_vrbl');
       axis([0,1,0,1]);
       header = ['R^2 =' num2str(r2),'coeffs:',num2str(quadmod)];
       title(header);
       saveas(gcf, sprintf('plot_%d.pdf', j));

       %residuals
       res = y_vrbl(thisBin) - quadmodcurve;
       plot(x_vrbl(thisBin),res,'+');
       header2 = ['residuals'];
       title(header2);
       saveas(gcf, sprintf('residuals_%d.pdf', j));

       end
       j = j + 1;
   end
end
```

**Explanation/Problem:**

`binCombos` is a 2 dimensional cell array and each cell has a non-uniform number of data points.  I am fitting a quadratic curve to the data for each unique cell, and trying (unsuccessfully) to output the **R^2 value** and also **plot residuals**.

I think the problem is related to the fact that the 'interval' required for the `polyval` function does not match the array size for `y_vrbl(thisBin)` when trying to find rsquare, and likewise for calculating the residuals.  For example, if I set `interval = x_vrbl(thisBin)` then the residuals "work" but the polyfit is all messed up.

Comment: As far as I can tell without being able to run this code, it should be correct the way you do it originally. What exactly is the problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: On second look: What does rsquare do? Can you post your implementation?

Comment: This is the routine I used for r^2: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34492-r-square-the-coefficient-of-determination/content/rsquare.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this should work:

```
quadmodcurve = polyval(quadmod,y_vrbl(thisBin)); 
[r2 rmse] = rsquare(y_vrbl(thisBin), quadmodcurve);
interval = 0.0:0.001:1;
quadmodcurve = polyval(quadmod,interval);
```

In order to determine the quality of fit, you have to evaluate the polynomial only at the x-values of the sample. In order to plot the full polynomial graph, you need to evaluate it at more and regularly spaced x-values.

Comment: Good start, this solved the problem of outputting the curve and data properly. However, I am getting mostly zeros for R^2 even when there is a significant amount of data and a good looking fit...?

Comment: Can you post a sample data set?

Comment: forgot to mention; the "row" and "column" bins can just be equal intervals in ascending/descending order. Thanks for taking a closer look!

Comment: I don't understand how to construct the bins. Maybe you could post the values of x_vrbl(thisBin) and y_vrbl(thisBin) for one of the bins?

Comment: Just added the code to construct the bins to my original post, let me know if this works or not

Comment: I think this initial solution works, it just needed x_vrbl instead of y_vrbl in the first polyval call.  Thanks a bunch for your answer and for helping me to look at the problem closer!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your code running with the data at http://dropproxy.com/f/4B6 and with the rsquare function from the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34492-r-square-the-coefficient-of-determination/content/rsquare.m)
after correcting some errors:

```
d = importdata('sample_data.xlsx');
y_vrbl = d.data(:, 1);
x_vrbl = d.data(:, 2);
rows = d.data(:, 3);
cols = d.data(:, 4);

cb = {0.050, 0.055, 0.060, 0.065, 0.070, 0.075, 0.080, 0.085, 0.090, 0.095,0.1};

for i = 1 : length(cb)-1
    colBIN{i,2} = find(cols(:,1) <= cell2mat(cb(i+1)) & cols(:,1) > cell2mat(cb(i)));
end

rb = {0.045, 0.046, 0.047, 0.048, 0.049, 0.050, 0.051, 0.052};

for i = 1 : length(rb)-1
    rowBIN{i,2} = find(rows(:,1) <= cell2mat(rb(i+1)) & rows(:,1) > cell2mat(rb(i)));
end

binCombos = cell(length(rowBIN)-1,length(colBIN)-1);

for m = 1 : length(rowBIN)-1
    for n = 1 : length(colBIN)-1
        binCombos{n,m} = intersect( rowBIN{m,2}(:,1),colBIN{n,2}(:,1));
    end
end


binRows = size(binCombos,1);
binCols = size(binCombos,2)-1;

j = 1;
for n = 1 : binRows;
    for m = 1 : binCols;
        thisBin = binCombos{n,m}(:,:);
        if ~isempty(thisBin)

            % polyfit
            quadmod = polyfit(x_vrbl(thisBin), y_vrbl(thisBin), 2);

            % compute residuals and R²
            quadmodcurve = polyval(quadmod,y_vrbl(thisBin));
            [r2, rmse] = rsquare(y_vrbl(thisBin), quadmodcurve);
            res = y_vrbl(thisBin) - quadmodcurve;

            % plot fit
            interval = 0.0:0.001:1;
            quadmodcurve = polyval(quadmod,interval);
            plot(x_vrbl(thisBin), y_vrbl(thisBin), '*', interval, quadmodcurve);
            xlabel('x_vrbl');
            ylabel('y_vrbl');
            axis([0,1,0,1]);
            header = ['R^2 =' num2str(r2),'coeffs:',num2str(quadmod)];
            title(header);
            saveas(gcf, sprintf('plot_%d.pdf', j));

            % plot residuals
            plot(x_vrbl(thisBin),res,'+');
            header2 = ['residuals'];
            title(header2);
            saveas(gcf, sprintf('residuals_%d.pdf', j));

        end
        j = j + 1;
    end
end
```

The fits look good to me, except that in most cases a linear function might be enough and the quadratic term is not necessary.

Regarding your remaining question: I'm not an expert on using R² for nonlinear fits (see note 2 on [Coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)), but the implementation you are using seems a bit fishy to me. The reason you get an output of 0 most of the time is the `max` function on line 65 of `rsquare.m` which prevents negative values from being returned. Since your polynomial fit does contain a constant term, calling the function as

```
[r2, rmse] = rsquare(y_vrbl(thisBin), quadmodcurve, false);
```

seems to be more appropriate, and results in R² > 0.9 in most cases.

My recommendation: Check whether R² is the correct measure of goodness of fit in your case, and check whether that function implements it correctly. Functions coming with Matlab can be trusted out of the box, but there is no quality guarantee for posts on the Matlab File Exchange.

Comment: Actually, more than a bit fishy: That `max` doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: per the comment below, I think the rsquare function works, I just had the wrong variable being used in polyval.  Anyway, I really appreciate your analysis of the problem. Thanks A!